# Search for metal brackets to join 1/4" plywood boxes

Tags: joinery, plywood, fasteners

Ikea used to make these boxes that were made out of 1/4" plywood connected with 8 galvanized metal brackets that had an extra lip on the top that helped keep the box together.

[image: Ikea Box]

I wanted to use the same method for making some boxes but I can't seem to find these kinds of brackets (pictured) anywhere.  I may be using the wrong keyword to search. I've tried box corner brackets with multiple variations to no avail. I've only found ones that don't have the lip at the top that grip the plywood.  The ones I've found only seem cosmetic and not structural.

[image: Bracket closeup, note the lip at the top that hugs the wood panel]

Does anyone know where one could find brackets like these mass produced?  I have asked local metal fabrication companies but they all say it would cost a lot to make custom ($30 a piece) I would need 8 that have a 1/4" lip that can grip the panels of the box into place.

Comment: Have you considered going to your local ikea and begging? There's a slim chance they'd have it, but I'd be willing to bet they'd give 'em away if they did have any.

Comment: Good idea if it was just for one box, but I'm looking to implement this as a solution for making many boxes.

Comment: @zoops I have seen corner braces online, but they do not wrap around a wood panel of a specific thickness.  I suspect this is a custom order item. Any sheet metal fabricator can make the pieces although they might only be interested in larger quantity orders. Maybe a smaller local company would be interested.  BTW the metal looks more like aluminum or stainless steel rather than galvanized.

Comment: If you can't find ones with the lip but can find ones without the lip use the latter and simply epoxy them on.

Comment: @Ashlar good suggestion.  I had reached out to some local fabricators and the general answer was yes we can make it but it would be expensive.  I found a guy who was going to make it for $30, which is a bit higher than what I wanted to pay for...

Comment: The problem with an item like this is that it would be highly dependent on the exact thickness of the material you're joining, and plywood is NOT a consistent thickness.  Each sheet is going to be thinner than the nominal dimension by anywhere between 0 and 1/32".  In fact, it's pretty common to find more than 1/64" variance within the same sheet.

Comment: This question is getting votes to close because it's asking for a specific product recommendation ("Where can I find xxx?"), which is specifically off-topic for this forum.  I'd recommend re-wording it to be more general ("What is this item called?")

Comment: Personally, what I'd do here is get two of the brackets for each corner and screw one to the outside of the material and one to the inside.

Comment: @zoops  Generally, when a supplier gives such a high price, they are politely saying they are not interested.  They will do it only if the profit is great enough to make it worth their time.  Now if you ordered a thousand, watch their unit price drop to useable rates.  The cost for making something like this is the setup time.

Answer (score 1):

There are places online you can order a custom piece like this if you want.

You could even 3D print it out of a metal or other tough material.

That said, I don't think that upper lip is doing anything for strength. If you put metal side brackets without any lip and you glue the joints, that can't move. Is it for aesthetic reasons? If so, could you cut something like this out with shears of sheet metal?

Comment: can you send me a link of a place I could custom order something like this online? Thanks

Comment: https://www.emachineshop.com

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet will be to look for "campaign furniture" corners.  A quick search turned up [this](https://www.paxtonhardware.com/product/campaign-chest-corners/corners-trim) for example.  Though, on re-reading your question, the linked example does not have the extra lip you want, I still think this is the right terminology for the thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A few search's led me the term "**plastic stacking corners**" OR "**box stacking corners**".

[Here](https://www.allenfield.com/product/plastic-top-corner-10mm/) is one example.

There are several kinds of those but i was not able to find metal ones.

I did find a [metal corner](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32859246117.html) that is not what you have referenced but could work.

It seems you could also use a piece of angle aluminum fastened around the the outside corner (*or inside corner*)  with screws, so it sits just higher then the top of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution at this point is to contact a local fabricator that can fabricate a piece like this since the exact thickness of the wood is needed in order to work with the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Try corner protector for boxes. I found some similar ones using that search. I didn’t try hard enough to find those exact brackets but some came close.